# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, xgboost, mlp

I want to use bagging with XGBoost an Mlpregression
If i use one algorithm it will work properly

```
XGBRegressor_bagging_model = BaggingRegressor(XGBRegressor_model,
                                              n_estimators=100,                                              
                                              max_samples=1.0, 
                                              max_features=1.0, 
                                              bootstrap=True,
                                              oob_score=True, 
                                              warm_start=False,
                                              n_jobs=-1,
                                              verbose=0)

MLP = BaggingRegressor(MLPRegressor_Model,
                       n_estimators=1000,
                       max_samples=1.0,
                       max_features=1.0,
                       bootstrap=True,
                       oob_score=True,
                       warm_start=False,
                       n_jobs=-1,
                       verbose=0)

XGBRegressor_bagging_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
MLP.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("XGBRegressor_bagging_model Predicted Is:", XGBRegressor_bagging_model.predict(X_test)[0:5])

print("MLP Predicted Is:", MLP.predict(X_test)[0:5])

print("XGBRegressor_bagging_model Score Is:", XGBRegressor_bagging_model.oob_score_)
print("MLP Score Is:", MLP.oob_score_)
```

but if i use it like this

```
bagging_model = BaggingRegressor((XGBRegressor_model, MLPRegressor_Model), n_estimators=100,max_samples=1.0, max_features=1.0, bootstrap=True, oob_score=True, warm_start=False, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
```

it wont work and show me this error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

what should i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your 2nd version, you're passing `(XGBRegressor_model, MLPRegressor_Model)` as the regressor. This is not a regressor, but rather a tuple (which happens to be composed of regressors). The error states that tuple does not have the method `fit`.

You should pass one of these regressors, or create a composite regressor from both.

Comment: please give me solution if it is possible to combine two model. after some search i could not find solution to do that. just i can find following link: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#composite-models-adding-or-multiplying-models

Comment: @Pixy Logically, how would you want to combine the two models? Each one outputs a prediction. Do you want to average the predictions? If so, by what weights? The answer depends on what you want to do.

Comment: i don't want to average the prediction's result. the first algorithm result would be the second one as input. weight would be 0.3

Comment: @Pixy Basically you need to create a pipeline. How exactly to do that is too large for the comments. Please look up sklearn's pipelines, then ask a different question if needed. Good luck.